# How did they create the soundtracks for old cartoons?

Tags: soundtrack, animation, musical

Take, for example, this [episode from Tom & Jerry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLxfIQ0Rf-Q).

Every movement/expression/feeling the characters display is included on the background music, which is a different thing than the usual sound effects used for a given action; and what impresses me most is the fact that these soundtracks had to be created and recorded episode by episode.

It's also nice to hear that they use the same composition throughout the episode in many different ways. In the case above, the composition used is [Chopin's Grande Valse Brillante](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2r7skqSkNM).

Is there any kind of documentary out there that explains how exactly people made these soundtracks?

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic

Comment: I'd like to add that you can easily make this on-topic by simply asking the question in your title - "How did they create the soundtracks for old cartoons?"

Comment: I believe it's like the way they did it for movies. Someone composed the songs, people played it, and sound effects were added for the sounds needed to represent the actions that you were witnessing.